# Exonerate Error while making

Tags: make, gcc

I'm using ProductName:
Mac OS X ProductVersion: 10.12.6 BuildVersion: 16G1212

trying to working with exonerate Tool but facing many troubles

configuration just went smooth

```
tamimis-Mac-Pro:exonerate anad$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for working aclocal-1.4... missing
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake-1.4... missing
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for working makeinfo... found
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking math.h usability... yes
checking math.h presence... yes
checking for math.h... yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking ctype.h usability... yes
checking ctype.h presence... yes
checking for ctype.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking time.h usability... yes
checking time.h presence... yes
checking for time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
Set host to i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
i386-apple-darwin16.7.0
Customising build for OSX
Set source_root_dir to /Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate
----------------------------------------------------------------
checking for socklen_t... yes
checking for pkg-config... /sw/bin/pkg-config
Using GLIB-2
Turning assertions off
Turning paranoid options off
Not using options for profiling with gprof
Not using options for analysis with gcov
Adding support for LARGE FILES (>2Gb) for a 32 bit system
Using COMPILED C4 MODELS
Installing UTILITIES
Using PTHREADS
----------------------------------------------------------------
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/man/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/man/man1/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/general/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sequence/Makefile
config.status: creating src/database/Makefile
config.status: creating src/struct/Makefile
config.status: creating src/comparison/Makefile
config.status: creating src/c4/Makefile
config.status: creating src/bsdp/Makefile
config.status: creating src/sdp/Makefile
config.status: creating src/hub/Makefile
config.status: creating src/model/Makefile
config.status: creating src/program/Makefile
config.status: creating src/util/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating test/util/Makefile
config.status: creating test/ipcress/Makefile
config.status: creating test/exonerate/Makefile
config.status: creating test/data/Makefile
config.status: creating test/data/cdna/Makefile
config.status: creating test/data/protein/Makefile
```

when I go the second Make an Error

make

```
Mu-Altamimis-Mac-Pro:exonerate mohanad$ make
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc'
Making all in man
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man'
Making all in man1
make[3]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man/man1'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man/man1'
make[3]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc/man'
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/doc'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src'
Making all in struct
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/struct'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/struct'
Making all in general
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/general'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/general'
Making all in sequence
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/sequence'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/sequence'
Making all in comparison
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/comparison'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/comparison'
Making all in database
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/database'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/database'
Making all in c4
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/c4'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/c4'
Making all in bsdp
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/bsdp'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/bsdp'
Making all in sdp
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/sdp'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/sdp'
Making all in model
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/model'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/model'
Making all in hub
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/hub'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/hub'
Making all in program
make[2]: Entering directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/program'
gcc  -g -O2 -I/sw/include/glib-2.0 -I/sw/lib/glib-2.0/include -DG_DISABLE_ASSERT -O3 -finline-functions -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DUSE_PTHREADS -L/sw/lib -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpthread -o exonerate  exonerate.o viterbi.o scheduler.o c4_model_archive.a                                            ../../src/comparison/wordhood.o                          ../../src/comparison/hspset.o                            ../../src/comparison/seeder.o                            ../../src/comparison/comparison.o                        ../../src/database/fastapipe.o                           ../../src/database/fastadb.o                             ../../src/struct/dejavu.o                                ../../src/struct/fsm.o                                   ../../src/struct/vfsm.o                                  ../../src/struct/sparsecache.o                           ../../src/hub/gam.o                                      ../../src/hub/bsam.o                                     ../../src/hub/analysis.o                                 ../../src/general/compoundfile.o                         ../../src/general/threadref.o                            ../../src/c4/c4.o                             ../../src/c4/codegen.o                        ../../src/c4/cgutil.o                         ../../src/c4/opair.o                          ../../src/c4/alignment.o                      ../../src/c4/optimal.o                        ../../src/c4/layout.o                         ../../src/c4/region.o                         ../../src/c4/subopt.o                         ../../src/bsdp/bsdp.o                         ../../src/bsdp/sar.o                          ../../src/bsdp/heuristic.o                    ../../src/bsdp/hpair.o                        ../../src/sdp/boundary.o                      ../../src/sdp/sdp.o                           ../../src/sdp/lookahead.o                     ../../src/sdp/straceback.o                    ../../src/struct/matrix.o                     ../../src/struct/slist.o                      ../../src/struct/pqueue.o                     ../../src/struct/recyclebin.o                 ../../src/struct/rangetree.o                  ../../src/sequence/sequence.o                 ../../src/sequence/alphabet.o                 ../../src/sequence/translate.o                ../../src/sequence/splice.o                   ../../src/model/affine.o                      ../../src/model/est2genome.o                  ../../src/model/ner.o                         ../../src/model/protein2dna.o                 ../../src/model/protein2genome.o              ../../src/model/coding2coding.o               ../../src/model/coding2genome.o               ../../src/model/cdna2genome.o                 ../../src/model/genome2genome.o               ../../src/model/ungapped.o                    ../../src/model/intron.o                      ../../src/model/frameshift.o                  ../../src/model/phase.o                       ../../src/model/modeltype.o                   ../../src/general/argument.o                  ../../src/general/lineparse.o                 ../../src/general/socket.o                    ../../src/general/jobqueue.o                  ../../src/comparison/match.o                  ../../src/sequence/submat.o                   ../../src/sequence/codonsubmat.o -lm -L/sw/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl
ld: warning: ignoring file c4_model_archive.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): c4_model_archive.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Bootstrapper_lookup", referenced from:
      _Viterbi_create in viterbi.o
      _Scheduler_create in scheduler.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Makefile:238: exonerate] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src/program'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:117: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Users/mohanad/Downloads/exonerate-master/exonerate/src'
make: *** [Makefile:127: all-recursive] Error 1
```

could someone please advice?

Comment: Are you getting the same error if you first do "make clean" and then "make" again?

Comment: i just did same error unfortunately

Comment: Try `autoreconf -fiv` before `./configure` step. I'v just done it and have successfully built. But I have MacOS 10.13.3.

Comment: i have update my mac to 10.13.3 and followed your instructions but end up with the same error 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)